# How to dynamically split a flattened XML in a data flow in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am importing XML files with the structure below.

[image: xml]

I am then transforming it with a data flow. First step I do is to unroll by `<Invoice>` tag and flatten. I know need to split in two different branches based on the invoiceNumber, because I need to output in separate JSON files for each invoiceNumber.

[image: dataflow]

I thought I could use a conditional split, but I don't know how to do the split dynamically, because I don't know the invoiceNumbers beforehand, so I cant hard-code them and besides, each XML file I import can have an unique invoice number or more than one, it will vary.

Any idea about how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to divide the file using invoice number, you can use the partition option available in sink transformation itself. Below is the approach.

- Add a new column named `filename` using derived column transformation and assign the value of  `Invoice_number` column.
  [image]
- Then take the sink transformation and in sink settings, give `Name file as column data` as File name option. Give `filename` as column data.

[image]

This will divide the file based on the **invoice_number** column itself and each file name will have the value of invoice number itself.

Comment: Hi Aswin, thanks, this is helpful. I tried and indeed now I have two separate files. Follow up questions, why do I have the files in my root folder and not in the subfolder as specified with the parameters? I have parametrized the JSON output dataset with 'container' and 'subfolder' and I input manually 'iata-is' for the container and 'in' for the subfolder, however, the partioned files end up in the container 'iata-is'. Do you know why?

Besides, the partioned ourput files do not have an extension, how could I give them a .json extension?

Comment: You can give the expression like `concat('<folder-name>/',Invoice_number,'.csv')` in the filename. This will make sure the file is created inside the folder and it has file extension also. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/uQ3nTn3.png)

Comment: Hi Aswin, indeed that works! Many many thanks